# Creatin a "main" window with ncurses for a game

Tags: window, ncurses

I'm trying to creat a window to be as a border for my entire game. So it will be the "main" window. I found out that the best way to do it is to create a "ghost" window and another, the real one which you'll use, inside of it with slighty less dimensions.

But I still can't proprely craate it: Heres my best solution yet.

```
#include <ncurses.h>

WINDOW* createWindow(int, int, int, int);
WINDOW* createRealWindow(int, int, int, int);

int main ()
{
    initscr();
    cbreak();

    char str[50];
    WINDOW *back_window, *real_window;
    int height=12, width=80;
    int x=(COLS-width)/2, y=(LINES-height)/2;

    back_window = createWindow(x, y, width, height);
    real_window = createRealWindow(x+1, y+1, width, height);
    wprintw(real_window, "Type: ");
    wgetstr(real_window, str);
    wrefresh(real_window);
    wprintw(real_window, "You typed %s.", str);
    wrefresh(real_window);

    napms(5000);
    endwin();

    return 0;
}

WINDOW* createWindow(int x, int y, int height, int width)
{
    WINDOW *local;

    local = newwin(width, height, y, x);
    box(local, 0, 0);
    wrefresh(local);

    return local;
}

WINDOW* createRealWindow(int x, int y, int height, int width)
{
    WINDOW *local;

    local = newwin(width-2, height-2, y+1, x+1);
    box(local, ' ', ' ');
    wrefresh(local);

    return local;
}
```

Here is my output:
[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26VSt.png)

Thanks guys!

*Edit: I've found the solution with the code down below, but I don't know how this will behave in others people computers with different resolutions. Ideas? PS: I use 1920 x 1080.*

```
int main ()
{
    initscr();
    cbreak();

    char str[50];
    WINDOW *back_window, *real_window;
    int height=22, width=78;
    int x=(COLS-width-1)/2, y=(LINES-height-2)/2;

    back_window = createWindow(x, y, width, height);
    real_window = createRealWindow(x+1, y+1, width, height);
    wprintw(real_window, "Type: ");
    wgetstr(real_window, str);
    wrefresh(real_window);
    wprintw(real_window, "You typed %s.", str);
    wrefresh(real_window);

    napms(5000);
    endwin();

    return 0;
}

WINDOW* createWindow(int x, int y, int height, int width)
{
    WINDOW *local;

    local = newwin(width+2, height+2, y, x);
    box(local, 0, 0);
    wrefresh(local);

    return local;
}

WINDOW* createRealWindow(int x, int y, int height, int width)
{
    WINDOW *local;

    local = newwin(width, height, y, x);
    wrefresh(local);

    return local;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *back_window* did not show up because the *real_window* obscured it (due to size/position).  But using `subwin` is the preferred way to do this:

```
#include <ncurses.h>

int main ()
{
    initscr();
    cbreak();

    char str[50];
    WINDOW *back_window, *real_window;
    int height=12, width=80;
    int x=(COLS-width)/2, y=(LINES-height)/2;

    back_window = newwin(height, width, y, x);
    box(back_window, 0, 0);
    wrefresh(back_window);

    real_window = subwin(back_window, height-2, width-2, y+1, x+1);

    wprintw(real_window, "Type: ");
    wgetstr(real_window, str);
    wrefresh(real_window);
    wprintw(real_window, "You typed %s.", str);
    wrefresh(real_window);

    napms(5000);
    endwin();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much.
Can you say if this code will create this same window size across different PCs/Resolutions at top left corner?

Or maybe I should be looking for ways to fix the terminal size...

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: The terminal size determines the values for **`COLS`** and **`LINES`** (given the same terminal size, you'll get the same window size).